# Builder pattern doesn't return "this"

Tags: spring, design-patterns

I used RestTemplateBuilder in spring boot today, and found its methods do not return "this", instead, they return a new builder instance.

```
public RestTemplateBuilder basicAuthorization(String username, String password) {
    return new RestTemplateBuilder(this.detectRequestFactory, this.rootUri,
            this.messageConverters, this.requestFactory, this.uriTemplateHandler,
            this.errorHandler, new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(username, password),
            this.restTemplateCustomizers, this.requestFactoryCustomizers,
            this.interceptors);
}
```

This is the first time I saw builder pattern not returning "this" at the end.
Is there any good reason to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builder pattern is not obligated to return `this` for each method. It's the implementation detail and it's encapsulated in the class itself.

As I can understand, it's done for the immutability, so you can use the same `RestTemplateBuilder` instance to create different `RestTemplate` instances.
Let's look at this example:

```
RestTemplateBuilder basicRestTemplateBuilder = new RestTmplateBuilder();
RestTemplate restTemplateWithBasicAuth = basicRestTemplateBuilder.basicAuthorization(username, password).build();
RestTemplate restTemlateWithUriTemplateHadler = basicRestTemplateBuilder.uriTemplateHandler(uriTemplateHandler).build();
```

You can safely reuse the same builder instance and don't worry that it will be configured wrong somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This class doesn't rely on the Builder pattern. 
It is a builder to create `RestTemplate` instances.  Whereas the name : `RestTemplateBuilder`.
The method to create a `RestTemplate` instance is :

```
public RestTemplate build() {
    return build(RestTemplate.class);
}
```

We can see that the instance of the `RestTemplateBuilder` class is created and returned by this public constructor (so not a builder pattern):

```
public RestTemplateBuilder(RestTemplateCustomizer... customizers) {
    Assert.notNull(customizers, "Customizers must not be null");
    this.detectRequestFactory = true;
    this.rootUri = null;
    this.messageConverters = null;
    this.requestFactorySupplier = null;
    this.uriTemplateHandler = null;
    this.errorHandler = null;
    this.basicAuthorization = null;
    this.restTemplateCustomizers = Collections
            .unmodifiableSet(new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(customizers)));
    this.requestFactoryCustomizers = Collections.emptySet();
    this.interceptors = Collections.emptySet();
}
```

And it seems that the class seems to be designed to be immutable.
So any methods defined in `RestTemplateBuilder` that change the current state don't return `this` but create a new instance with the applied change.

Similarly to what the immutable classes such as  `LocalDate` or `String` do.